# Preprocessing HTML CSS JS for iText

Tags: javascript, java, itext7

I am trying to use iText embedded in Java code to turn a webpage built with HTML/CSS/JS into a PDF. However, iText has informed us that while pdfHTML supports CSS, it does not support JS. They recommended using a preprocessor to "run" the Javascript in the page and get back the raw HTML.

Without the Javascript, iText is generating the PDF pretty well. However, we need to be able to inject data from a service call into the HTML. I used JQuery to accomplish this. We are also calling and using FusionCharts API to render some charts. These are also working until the PDF generation.

Does anyone know of anything like this? It needs to be able to be called from our Java back end, also.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways of evaluating JS code on HTML + CSS + JS pages. To do that we need an analogue of a browser (or a browser itself), because evaluation of JS with DOM manipulation is exactly what browsers have to do before rendering pages.

#### Option 1

Use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net) - a "GUI-Less browser for Java programs".

First, we need to add the dependency (e.g. via Maven):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
  <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
  <version>2.32</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, open the page, wait for JS to complete its work and feed the page source to iText pdfHTML:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
// You might need this configuration if HtmlUnit fails without it
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10 * 1000);
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
String xml = page.asXml();

ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties().setBaseUri(url);
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(source, new PdfWriter("result.pdf"), properties);
```

HtmlUnit does not fully support JS, so it might throw errors when evaluating JS code. Therefore, you might want to suppress them (I've added this configuration and a comment about it to the code sample). Of course, your result might look incorrect. But this is pure Java solution.

#### Option 2

Ask some help from the real world browsers we use every day

Browsers that we use every day (Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc) have the best support of the JS evaluation. You can make use of the browser engines by using e.g. [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org) web automation tool. What we will be doing is opening a page in a browser, waiting until page loads and then using the source for HTML -> PDF conversion. My example will be for Chrome, but you can do it in a similar way for other browsers. First, you will need to [download](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.44/) a Chrome driver and unpack it somewhere on your system.

Then add the following Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now we have to write some code, similar to the first option:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(url);
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
String source = driver.getPageSource();
driver.close();

ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties().setBaseUri(url);
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(source, new PdfWriter("result.pdf"), properties);
```

This option might be a bit slower and has more prerequisites (browser, drivers) but it guarantees bulletproof JS support.

Comment: Wow, this is a great comment. Thank you for taking the time to do all of this. I am going to implement it this week and see if I can get it to work, but it is definitely an answer so I am going to accept it as such!

Comment: And yeah, Selenium with the Chrome Driver turned out to be the best answer for our specific problem. Thank you again @Alexey